# Find basis to sub vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

V = $\Bbb R_3 [x]$ and W,U $\subseteq$ V are sub vector spaces.
U=$span${$1 - x, x^2, x^2-x^3, -1+x-x^2+2x^3$}
W={p(x)$\in\Bbb R_3 [x]$ | p(1)=0 ^ p(2)+p(0)=0} 
Find basis to W, U+W, U$\cap$W

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your work; this isn't a website aimed at solving your homework.

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: Search this site, starting with the handy list of related questions at right. Similar questions have been answered time and time again.